# How to change username in org.springframework.security.core.Authentication object value

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security

I want to set username in org.springframework.security.core.Authentication object which is obtained from authentication manager(i.e from authenticationManager.authenticate()). I want to change user name to eiether upper or lower case. is it possible?

I do not see any setter for that in Authentication object. Please help me in this.

Comment: Can you share your webSecurityConfig code for clarity on your implementation !!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("whatever username you want", null);
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
```